# Basic MDM Server setup

Tags: ios, macos, mdm

I am trying to create APNS certificate to setup basic MDM server. I am following this link http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf

I have OS X server 10.8, an an Apple developer account.

I have enabled APN using server application in mac osx server. When I edit or try creating new certificate its takes me to https://identity.apple.com/pweb/?r=1 here it requires CSR signed from third party vendor. Which I dont have.

So how to create APNS certificate from mac osx server 10.8 without having Enterprise account?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, are you trying to become a vendor or are a customer of a vendor?

If you are a customer, you don't need anything other than an apple account, you could ask for instructions from your vendor, more specifically, a Signed Certificate Signing Request(scsr) from your vendor. Then upload this file to the URL that you provide to get a APNS push certificate.

But if you are trying to become a vendor or want to create your own MDM server, you will need to have an enterprise account, and make sure the account has mdm option when first applied for this account.

More information can be found in Apple's doc of Mobile Device Management Protocol
http://adcdownload.apple.com//Documents/mobile_device_management_protocol/mobiledevicemanagement_121211.pdf